# Apache Druid vs Snowflake

Tags: data-warehouse, olap, druid, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm choosing the proper Tools for BI/OLAP and need understand whether Snowflake or Druid is more suitable for my goals.

Currently I'm using Snowflake as my Data Warehouse, and it serves both

1. raw data queries (with massive dataset responses)
2. aggregated results

In order to achieve performance of the second type, I'm creating additional aggregation tables, which acts as an OLAP cube.
My data is time-based.

However, this method demands additional work, as well as data duplication and static query requirements.

Therefore, I'm considering to adopt apache Druid, which will provide solution for the aggregation.

Is Druid capable of replacing Snowflake for the raw dataset, assuming the the queries will always be bound by the time range, and that I can use scan-queries? Or must I keep both DBs?